# Return subclass when calling parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to get instance of one of subclasses when trying get instance of a superclass (parent class) depending on arguments. For example, I have parent class(I'm using python3):

```
class Man:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello! My name is {}.".format(self.name))
```

And subclass:

```
class YoungMan(Man):

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hey, man! Wazap?")
```

If age of Man less 30, I want it become YoungMan:

```
John = Man('John', 25)
type(John) #<class '__main__.YoungMan'>
John.say_hello() #Hey, man! Wazap?
```

I tried solve it with `Man.__new__()`:

```
class Man:

    def __new__(cls, name, age):
        if age < 30:
            return YoungMan(name, age)
        else:
            return super(Man, cls).__new__()
    ...
```

But `John.say_hello()` returns `Hello! My name is John.` So `Man` methods override `YoungMan` methods. After I tried use metaclass for `Man`:

```
class ManFactory(type):

    def __call__(self, name, age):
        if age < 30:
            return YoungMan(name, age)

class Man(metaclass=ManFactory):
    ...
```

But it lached on `ManFactory.__call__()`.

I understand that I can use a funtion `John = get_Man(name, age)` which returns right class, but it isn't so handsome. My question is about how do it like this:

```
John = Man('John', 25)
type(John) #<class '__main__.YoungMan'>
John.say_hello() #Hey, man! Wazap?

Brad = Man('Brad', 54)
type(Brad) #<class '__main__.Man'>
Brad.say_hello() #Hello! My name is Brad.
```

Comment: I find such design contradicting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is good practice but you could set `self.__class__`:

```
class Man:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        if age < 30: self.__class__ = YoungMan
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello! My name is {}.".format(self.name))


class YoungMan(Man):

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hey, man! Wazap?")


a = Man("Brad", 15)
print(type(a))
>>><class '__main__.YoungMan'>
a.say_hello()
>>>Hey, man! Wazap?
```

The main problem with this method is that the YoungMan would still be constructed by `Man.__init__()` so the classes would have to be compatible. Creating a function `get_man()` is still the best solution.

Comment: this works fine in practice. what I do is to have a ‘def \_init’ and call it at the end of the main \__init\__.  subclasses can then do their own stuff.  and the classes need to be compatible in any factory-type scenario.  then again you put this class-swapping mechanism in a factory method -less surprising.